# Express node js 404 error

Tags: javascript, ajax, node.js, express

I am struggling with a 404 error when I attempt to post an ajax request using the below code"

```
// Use AJAX to post the object to our addReport service
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: newReport,
        url: '/add/addreport',
        dataType: 'JSON'
    })
```

My app.js contains the routes

```
var routes = require('./routes/index');
var reports = require('./routes/reports');
var add = require('./routes/add');
```

and

```
app.use('/', routes);
app.use('/reports', reports);
app.use('/add', add);
```

and then in the route file I have

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/*
 * GET reportList.
 */
router.get('/reportlist', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('reports').find().toArray(function (err, items) {
        res.json(items);
    });
});


/*
 * POST to addreport
 */
router.get('/addreport', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('reports').insert(req.body, function(err, result){
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
        );
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

The GET request works fine. But I get a 404 on the POST (addreport).

I think I have all the necessary parts but I am new to express. Perhaps I am missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should change your method on the route you are using get as well for 'addreport'

try to change it to post like this:

```
router.post('/addreport', function(req, res) {
    var db = req.db;
    db.collection('reports').insert(req.body, function(err, result){
        res.send(
            (err === null) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: err }
        );
    });
});
```

Comment: So simple. Thats what I get for copy and paste from my previous function. Thank you

Comment: that happened to me a lot of times! just remember when you get a 404 to check your method on your router! cheers!